# Add a custom attribute do session with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to put an custom attribute to the session created by Spring Security.

I tried to do this with using the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. I configured this custom filter on my spring configuration on this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/SpringMessages" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my_database" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
        <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" autowire-candidate="default">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationDetails" class="com.mycompany.mysystem.login.configuration.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.mysystem.*"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <security:http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login?status=error" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?status=logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/acesso" />
        <security:headers disabled="true"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customAuthenticationDetails" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="my users"
                authorities-by-username-query="my authorities" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans>
```

And my CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:

```
package com.mycompany.mysystem.login.configuration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.mycompany.mysystem.register.dao.FuncionarioDAO;
import com.mycompany.mysystem.register.model.Funcionario;

    public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

        @Autowired
        private FuncionarioDAO funcionarioDAO;

        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

            Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();

            try {
                funcionario = funcionarioDAO.getFuncByLogin(request.getParameter("j_username"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            request.getSession().setAttribute("usuarioLogado", funcionario);

            return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);

        }

    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? I think its a concept error, but I don't found any solution to add an custom attribute to the spring session.

Best regards,

Edited.

My Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>MySystem</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Edit2.

I solved this problem with another approach, so it cant be posted on this topic, but the problem was solved.

Comment: post your web.xml please

Comment: What and why do you need to add something.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need one information of the user table (funcionario) in all my controllers (because: don't ask why and the architeture just do it) if you understand. I think in get this information ever I need, but make a connection in all controllers looks more poor than passing through session.

Comment: The user is already part of the session, why not simply create your own user object and use that instead of the default Spring Security user? That way you can simply add a parameter to every controller method (i.e a `Principal` or `Authentication`) to get access. Saves you manually storing it in the session and integrate nicely with the rest of the framework. But if you really want to just create an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to do it for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did it replacing the default Spring Security User and it works correctly! Thanks for the tip.